# C++ Cast to "uncle class"

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, casting, shared-ptr

I have a `Wrapper<T>` template class.

I have a base class A.

I have a derived class B : public A.

What I want is to store a `Wrapper<B>` in a `vector<Wrapper<A>>`.

I know this technically not right as `Wrapper<B>` is not a direct subclass of `Wrapper<A>`

[See inheritance diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eczdz.jpg)

But somehow, STL allow that for shared_ptr:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A() {}
  virtual ~A() {}
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : public A
{
  B() {}
  virtual ~B() {}
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> v;

  v.push_back(std::make_shared<A>());
  v.push_back(std::make_shared<B>());

  for (auto &e : v)
    e->print();

  return 0;
}
```

How can I achieve the same result for my `Wrapper<T>` class ?

This is the non-compiling code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct W
{
};

struct A
{
  A() {}
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : public A
{
  B() {}
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<W<A>> v;

  v.push_back(W<A>());
  v.push_back(W<B>());

  for (auto &e : v)
    e->print();

  return 0;
}
```

Best,
Pierre

Comment: "_I have a Wrapper template class._" How is it defined? What functionality, in regards to it, do you want?

Comment: a `B` *is-a* `A`, you don't need `shared_ptr<B>`, a `shared_ptr<A>` can hold a `B` instance. If you need this distinction I smell poor design.

Comment: Post code that shows the problem.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Wrapper is a simplification to keep the question simple. In my real world use case, I have a vector<Product> that holds Product & ProductDerivative objects (Product derivative being a subclass of Product).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Wrapper is a simplification to keep the question simple. In my real world use case, I have a `vector<Product>` that holds `Product` & `ProductDerivative` objects (`ProductDerivative` being a subclass of `Product`). In my case, the Wrapper is called `RollbackElement<T> : public T` and provide a `commit()` and `rollback()` method. The point is that `RollbackElement` keeps a copy of a stable state of the object and allow you to make revertible modifications. I'm getting stuck at the point where I'm trying to change `vector<Product>` into `vector<RollbackElement<Product>>`.

Comment: @PeteBecker `#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct W
{

};

struct A
{
  A() {}
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : public A
{
  B() {}
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<W<A>> v;

  v.push_back(W<A>());
  v.push_back(W<B>());

  for (auto &e : v)
    e->print();

  return 0;
}
`

Comment: The code **in your question** should show the problem. Put that code into the question in place of the code that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared ptr to A and B are unrelated types.

What shared ptr does is provide a converting constructor.  So long as the pointer-types can be converted, it accepts both raw-pointer-to and shared-ptr-to.

Shared ptr type erases how to do the final destruction, and stores the pointer, so this really isn't hard.

How exactly this works will depend on how the data is stoted and what Wrapper does.

But:

```
template<class T>
struct Wrapper {
  template<class U>
  Wrapper(Wrapper<U>);
};
```

is basically it.  Maybe some SFINAE to get earlier errors.

...

As you have actually added details in comments, you have:

```
template<class T>
struct RollbackElement : public T
```

as `Wrapper`.  The answer is, no, you cannot do that.

You can do:

```
template<class T>
struct RollbackElement : public std::any {
  operator T&() {
    return std::any_cast<T&>(*this);
  }
};
```

where instead of storing an *actual* `T`, you store a type-erasing wrapper around a `T`.

```
template<class T>
struct RollbackElement : private std::any {
  operator T&() {
    return *get();
  }
  operator T const&() const {
    return *get();
  }
  RollbackElement( T in ):
    std::any(std::move(in)),
    get_impl([](std::any& x)->T*{return std::any_cast<T*>(&x);})
  {}
  RollbackElement():RollbackElement({}) {}
  template<class U>
  RollbackElement( RollbackElement<U> const& o ):
    std::any( static_cast<std::any const&>(o) ),
    get_impl(o.get_impl)
  {}
  // note: due to quirks in `std::any`, a move ctor isn't safe
  T* operator->() { return get(); }
  T const* operator->() const { return get(); }
  T* get() { return get_impl(*this); }
  T const* get() const { return get_impl(const_cast<std::any&>(*this)); }
private:
  std::function<T*(std::any&)> get_impl = {};
};
```

plus whatever augmentation you want on it.

The trick here is that your storage, a `std::any`, can store anything.

We store how to get from `std::any` to a `T*` in `get_impl`.

When we copy a `RollbackElement` we copy both the any (without casting to a concrete type) *and* the `get_impl`.  If the other Rollback is a *different* type, we rely on the converting constructor of `std::function` to adjust the returned pointers for us.

Comment: Thanks, my codebase is stuck at C++11 dur to company policy, so std::any isn't an option for me, but I can probably figure something out using converting constructor ;)

Comment: @PierreWilmot `boost::any` or write your own (ouch).  The features of `std::any` are required if you want to *actually* store a derived instead of a base; a vector of base is different than a vector of derived pretending to be a vector of base.  You could use `std::shared_ptr<T>` but that massively changes semantics.